# Where Do I Download the "geth removedb" tool & how do I use it, Step by Step?

Tags: mist

I am reading that many people who are having problems with Mist gobbling up hard drive space (in my case 135 GB - I'm serious - there should be a 5 inch read warning when you download MIST about this - and of course it nearly killed my 251 GB hard drive) that they should use "geth removedb" to fix this. Unfortunately no one ever explains **where or how to download this tool OR how to use it**. Is there a support site?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `chaindata` folder, which should be located somewhere here:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Mist
```

or here:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Ethereum
```

---

**OR** using the `geth`, download and install it [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) and run:

```
geth removedb
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: Don't delete `keystore` folder. Back up your keystore file.